# bootstrap column gets enlarged by an image

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, pug, responsive

I have a `row`containing some `col-md`. In the last column I have an image and when rendering the website on an mobile phone, the last column gets enlarged by the image and displaced into a new row.

[image: normal rendering]

[image: phone rendering]

**jade:**

```
div.row#contact
   div.col-md-3
   div.col-md-2
   div.col-md-1
   div.col-md-1
   div.col-md-1
   div.col-md-1      
   div.col-md-3
     img(src = "./images/wko_logo.svg", alt = "wko logo")
```

**scss:**

```
img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap's grid system uses sm columns until the container width drops below 768px, as defined in https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options. When it drops below that width, it'll give each `.col-sm-*` div 100% width. Give your html elements a behaviour for an xs container width, and your problem is solved.

A working example can be found at https://jsfiddle.net/fqxg3L9p/.